# MySQL merging partitions showing error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to merge partition created on daily bases based on timestamp but getting error.

I have created partition like this

```
$tomorrow = strtotime("tomorrow midnight");
$partition = date('dmy',$tomorrow);

ALTER TABLE `stats`
ADD PARTITION (
PARTITION p_$partition VALUES LESS THAN ($tomorrow)
)";
```

Then I do this to get daily partition

```
ALTER TABLE `stats`
PARTITION BY RANGE (`date`) (
PARTITION p_$partition VALUES LESS THAN ($tomorrow)
)
```

Now I need to merge all partition up till today into single partition doing this way

```
ALTER TABLE `stats` REORGANIZE PARTITION 
p_190416,p_200416.....
INTO (
PARTITION p_$partition VALUES LESS THAN ($tomorrow)
);
```

But its showing me error as

> Fatal error: Reorganize of range partitions cannot change total ranges except for last partition where it can extend the range in

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this without loosing data.